# How to write Ingress controller for multiple endpoints in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have to write Ingress controller in AKS for multiple deployed service.

Use case.

1. I have created the function app images and deployed them in AKS Cluster
2. Now Individual service has the endpoints and I tested it individually it's working fine and giving the response.

Problem:

I have written the ingress controller and used the rewrite-target somehow its works for a single API but when I am using the rewrite-target multiple time then the existing one is not working only the latest one is working.

Code:

````
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: containerpoc
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/AccountBalance?account
     #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/Refining?account
     #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/RefiningDetail?CustRefNum
     #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/Transactions?accounts
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /account
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: accountbalance-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /account/balanceref
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: accountbalance-service
            port:
              number: 80 
      - path: /transaction
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: transactions-service
            port:
              number: 80 ```

The above code is working for a single API but I need to make it for multiple API/endpoints
The ask is how to set up the ingress which can support multiple API route-based URL

I am expecting the URL to look like

In browser

IP/Account?account=1
IP/Transaction?account=1
IP/refining?CustomRefnum=&&Ref=2323-oo&DateReceived=03-May-2023&account=0000

Thanks
Sudhir
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define multiple ingress in different namespace for respective service/url.
Or create new ingress object with different name for each api endpoint.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-refining
  namespace: containerpoc
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    #  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/AccountBalance?account
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/Refining?account
     #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/RefiningDetail?CustRefNum
     #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/Transactions?accounts
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /account
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: accountbalance-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /account/balanceref
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: accountbalance-service
            port:
              number: 80 
      - path: /transaction
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: transactions-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: I have total 13 microservices so its good idea to create 13 new ingress files? also does it create new public IP? because I need one public IP and al microservices should map with same.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple ingress in different namespace for respective service/url.
Or create new ingress object with different name for each api endpoint.

Comment: Can you give me some refrence , I am very new in the AKS world

Comment: updated answer inline